# Odd behaviour when uploading .svg Assets

Tags: assets, svg

Running 2.6.2983 on OS Sierra.

I'm noticing that some of my SVG files when uploading are going from 50kb to 1kb and then appear completely blank when trying to view them. Does anyone have a clue why this would be happening?

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please email support@craftcms.com for assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Half-bug, half side-effect/undesired behavior for SVG sanitization that got added in [Craft 2.6.2982](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-6-2982) for SVGs that use embedded data.

The next release of Craft (post 2.6.2983) adds a `sanitizeSvgUploads` config setting (`true` by default) that you will be able to set to false to disable SVG sanitization.

Comment: Nice to see it fixed so quickly